# How to read MANIFEST file of a particular class path jar in java program

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I am able to read MANIFEST file of all my class path jars in my java program. But i want to read MANIFEST file of a particular jar say "xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar" How it can be done?

My working code is

```
Enumeration resEnum;
    try{
    resEnum  =Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResources(JarFile.MANIFEST_NAME);

    while (resEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
        try {
            URL url = (URL)resEnum.nextElement();
            InputStream is = url.openStream();

            if (is != null) {
                Manifest manifest = new Manifest(is);

                Attributes mainAttribs = manifest.getMainAttributes();
                String vendor = mainAttribs.getValue("Implementation-Vendor");
                String version = mainAttribs.getValue("Implementation-Version");
                if(!mainAttribs.getValue("Extension-Name").equals("null")){
                    System.out.println(mainAttribs.getValue("Implementation-Title"));
                                           System.out.println(version);
                    System.out.println(vendor);
                    System.out.println(mainAttribs.getValue("Extension-Name"));
                }
                }
            }catch(Exception e){}
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
if (url.getFile().contains("xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar")) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Probably missing something, but how does this help get the contents of the MANIFEST?

Comment: It just helps to select the required jar, this is what the question was about.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [JarFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html) class and get the Manifest using [getManifest()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html#getManifest%28%29) method.

Comment: "C:/maven_repo/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar" this is path to log4j lib and i am using code like final File f = new File("C:/maven_repo/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar");JarFile jar = new JarFile(f); Manifest manifest = jar.getManifest();
But i am unable to read manifest attributes all are null i am geeting

Comment: Are any exceptions thrown? That code works for me on a Linux box for that jar